# How to create a twitter like 3-column responsive UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm building twitter clone and it's UI have a 3 column layout.

[Working Implementation](https://il3x7.csb.app/)

When access it from desktop, it shows like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
| Navbar| Feed | Follow |
-------------------------------------------
```

When access it from tablet or mid size device, it shows like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
| Navbar| Feed |
-------------------------------------------
```

When access it from mobile or small size device, it shows like this(Navbar should be at bottom):

```
--------------------------------------------------
|                      Feed                      |


| Nav-item-1| Nav-item-2 | Nav-item-3| Nav-item-4|
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'm successful in making layout responsive for tablet and desktop but for mobile I'm having issues.

This is what I have tried:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .bootomTab {
    display: flex !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }
}
```

Full Code:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="row">
        <nav className="bootomTab d-none d-sm-flex col-sm-2 col-lg-3">
          <div>
            <div className="logo">
              <a href="/home">
                <img src="/twitter.png" alt="logo" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <a href="/home">
              <i className="fas fa-home"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/search">
              <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/notifications">
              <i className="fas fa-bell"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/messages">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/profile">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="/signout">
              <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div className="mainSectionContainers col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-5 ml-2">
          <div className="titleContainer">
            <h1>Home</h1>
          </div>
          Feed
        </div>
        <div className="d-none d-lg-flex col-md-2 col-lg-4 mt-5">
          {/* Follow suggestions */}
          <aside className="followSuggestion">
            <div className="followSuggestionHeader">
              <h2>Who to follow</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="followUsernameContainer">
              <div className="userImageContainer">
                <img src="/defaultProfilePic.jpg" alt="user pic" />
              </div>
              <div className="midFollowContainer">
                <div className="displayName">
                  <span>Yogesh Yadav</span>
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                  <span>@yogeshdecodes</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="buttonContainer">
                <button id="submitPostButton">Follow</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="followUsernameContainer">
              <div className="userImageContainer">
                <img src="/defaultProfilePic.jpg" alt="user pic" />
              </div>
              <div className="midFollowContainer">
                <div className="displayName">
                  <span>Yogesh Yadav</span>
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                  <span>@yogeshdecodes</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="buttonContainer">
                <button id="submitPostButton">Follow</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="followUsernameContainer">
              <div className="userImageContainer">
                <img src="/defaultProfilePic.jpg" alt="user pic" />
              </div>
              <div className="midFollowContainer">
                <div className="displayName">
                  <span>Yogesh Yadav</span>
                </div>
                <div className="username">
                  <span>@yogeshdecodes</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="buttonContainer">
                <button id="submitPostButton">Follow</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS Code:

```
div .logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

div .logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
}

nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212529;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: var(--buttonHoverBg);
  color: var(--primary-blue);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.mainSectionContainers {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -10px 0 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
}

.titleContainer {
  height: 53px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.followSuggestion {
  background-color: rgb(247, 249, 249);
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.followSuggestionHeader {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
}

.followSuggestionHeader h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.followUsernameContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
}

.midFollowContainer {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.userImageContainer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.userImageContainer img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

#submitPostButton {
  background-color: #1fa2f1;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .bootomTab {
    display: flex !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }
  
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to make it fully responsive.

The issue is because of the wrong breakpoint(480px) I have set and extra div present outside nav-items which override parent class property.

Changes I have made in css:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .bootomTab {
    display: flex !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6ecf0;
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }
  .bootomTab a {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobileHide{
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

On desktop, it shows like this:
[image]

On tablet, it shows like this:
[image]

On mobile, it shows like this:

[image]